# iterate over pandas columns of type ndarray

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, the first one is an id and the other column is an array. This column is an array of arrays (ndarray) containing NaN values. (I have already passed the first step which was to convert it since it was in bytes. And it is possible that when making this change the column is of type str.)

```
terrain['ndvi_matrix'] = np.array(terrain.ndvi_matrix.str.decode('utf-8'))
terrain

terrain_id  ndvi_matrix
0   1   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
1   2   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
2   3   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
3   4   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
4   5   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
5   6   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
6   7   [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
7   23  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
8   27  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
9   28  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
10  35  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], [0.3127734033...
11  36  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
12  42  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
13  50  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
14  51  [[NaN, 0.18129175946547885, 0.1526586620926243...
15  52  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
16  55  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
17  56  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
18  57  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], [NaN, 0.38725...
19  58  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
20  59  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
21  61  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], [NaN, NaN, Na...
22  62  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN], [0.0791249233...
23  63  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
24  64  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN,...
25  67  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
26  68  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
27  73  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
28  74  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
29  77  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
30  79  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
31  80  [[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694...
```

```
terrain.dtypes
terrain_id      int64
ndvi_matrix    object
dtype: object
```

What I want is to iterate over the values of these rows and put conditions. For example, for values greater than 0.5 UPDATE the value by 0.99. I'm also having problems with NaNs, since when I iterate with a for and iterrows, it tells me that the column is of type str.

I have tried this, but it does not update the dataframe(In this case I do the encode using jsonloads)

```
for index, row in terrain.iterrows():
  terrain_id = row['terrain_id']
  ndvi_matrix = np.array(json.loads(row['ndvi_matrix']))
  for col in ndvi_matrix:
    for pixel in col:
      if pixel > 0.5:
        pixel = 0.99
      elif 0.2 < pixel < 0.5:
        Fc = ((pixel - 0.2) ** 2)/0.09 
        pixel = Fc
      elif pixel < 0.2:
        pixel = 0.944
      else:
        pixel = 'nan'
      
      print(pixel)
```

Eixample:

```
array(['[[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694915254237, 0.3121476166068683, 0.43469446857804805, 0.35864022662889516, NaN, NaN], [NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.39893805309734515, 0.5044690740078656, 0.5433070866141733, 0.5176265270506109, 0.4300861497680583, 0.31038343129023227, 0.41292379020573744, 0.4365527488855869, NaN, NaN], [NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.5380281690140845, 0.5721357850070722, 0.5886981402002861, 0.5908611599297012, 0.6074124914207275, 0.6179540709812108, 0.6184530003468609, 0.6147846727704307, 0.5858347386172007, NaN], [NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.605643994211288, 0.613724796604174, 0.6004250797024442, 0.603299856527977, 0.609429978888107, 0.6084546084546084, 0.626489138051857, 0.6185567010309279, 0.5827633378932968, NaN], [NaN, NaN, 0.6287215411558669, 0.6118980169971672, 0.6051532033426184, 0.6032303370786517, 0.6175839885632595, 0.6167146974063401, 0.6188786373314408, 0.628808864265928, 0.6193103448275862, 0.5957671957671957, NaN], [NaN, NaN, 0.6093189964157706, 0.5889921372408864, 0.5956552207428171, 0.608649415101028, 0.6209705986539142, 0.6205533596837944, 0.6292857142857143, 0.6296036478428622, 0.6120659417748159, 0.5862311204776958, NaN], [NaN, NaN, 0.59375, 0.5653429602888087, 0.589817138759412, 0.5995694294940797, 0.607563325008919, 0.6096333572969087, 0.6217345872518286, 0.6243441762854145, 0.6021390374331551, 0.6045118082481494, NaN], [NaN, NaN, 0.5848920863309353, 0.5734011627906976, 0.6040100250626567, 0.6092691622103387, 0.6002865329512894, 0.582879941965905, 0.5781518378564068, 0.6072676450034941, 0.5981375358166189, 0.6016771488469602, NaN], [NaN, 0.5665236051502146, 0.5756026296566837, 0.5879140880961048, 0.615983026874116, 0.6137339055793991, 0.5862068965517241, 0.5815808556925308, 0.585934696806602, 0.5968034871049764, 0.5933789132781576, 0.5913073957237995, NaN], [NaN, 0.5614353026458861, 0.582338038364097, 0.5881929445644348, 0.6124737210932025, 0.606952820148989, 0.573746844572665, 0.6049733570159858, 0.6176678445229682, 0.6090491339696006, 0.6205092431112661, 0.6100981767180925, NaN], [NaN, 0.5616045845272206, 0.5915744377008212, 0.5772870662460567, 0.5922535211267606, 0.5998591053187742, 0.5921513665031535, 0.6301703163017032, 0.6083421703782255, 0.6028169014084507, 0.6353629170966633, 0.6252602359472589, NaN], [NaN, 0.5752895752895753, 0.6055944055944056, 0.5848400556328234, 0.587513153279551, 0.6028169014084507, 0.6085902320748181, 0.6206185567010309, 0.6098591549295774, 0.5980528511821975, 0.6147994467496543, 0.6101283385362469, NaN], [NaN, 0.6063756063756064, 0.6014735432016075, 0.5934178950977032, 0.6148300720906282, 0.5845942228335625, 0.5820486467968482, 0.6119917298414886, 0.5669050051072523, 0.5611390284757118, 0.5912897822445561, 0.564563582870219, NaN], [0.4517675254643499, 0.4760514018691589, 0.4551226551226551, 0.414577931431864, 0.4381895332390382, 0.42126436781609194, 0.3607280750137893, 0.3523246439129266, 0.3677453864669698, 0.3598930481283422, 0.34667359667359665, 0.3580502981591911, NaN], [NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN]]'],
      dtype=object)
```

Comment: `ndvi_matrix` is a string or numpy array?

Comment: I transform to np.array but I don't know how it gets the NaN values, I guess in str format

Comment: Your input data is not usable. Copy/Paste one full raw string. We can't guess the shape of each row.

Comment: I have edited the question with an example

Comment: Is it possible to have the original `terrain['ndvi_matrix']` before decoding?

Comment: I can only get this, I can't get it whole   `b'[[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.36016..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this help? This will create a new column with any applied logic defined in the function.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'arr': [np.array([[np.nan, .55, .02 , .88]]), np.array([[np.nan, .55, .02 , .88]])]}

terrain= pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['arr'])

def arr_logic(arr):
    new_arr = []
    for pixel in arr[0]:
        if pixel > 0.5:
            new_arr.append(0.99)
        elif 0.2 < pixel < 0.5:
            Fc = ((pixel - 0.2) ** 2)/0.09
            new_arr.append(Fc)
        elif pixel < 0.2:
            new_arr.append(0.944)
        else:
            new_arr.append(pixel)

    return [new_arr]

terrain['new_arr'] = terrain['arr'].apply(lambda x: arr_logic(x))
print(terrain.dtypes)
print(terrain)


arr        object
new_ary    object
dtype: object
                         arr                     new_arr
0  [[nan, 0.55, 0.02, 0.88]]  [[nan, 0.99, 0.944, 0.99]]
1  [[nan, 0.55, 0.02, 0.88]]  [[nan, 0.99, 0.944, 0.99]]
[Finished in 0.55s]
```

Here is some processing you can do on the example array you provided. It probably better extract the array with the proper formatting before iterating within the df.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'arr': [b'[[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694915254237, 0.3121476166068683, 0.43469446857804805, 0.35864022662889516]]',
 b'[[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.3601694915254237, 0.3121476166068683, 0.43469446857804805, 0.35864022662889516]]']}

terrain= pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['arr'])

def arr_logic(arr):
    new_arr = []
    arr = re.sub(r"\[|\]", '', arr)
    arr = [np.nan if i =='NaN' else float(i) for i in arr.split(",")]

    for pixel in arr:
        if pixel > 0.5:
            new_arr.append(0.99)
        elif 0.2 < pixel < 0.5:
            Fc = ((pixel - 0.2) ** 2)/0.09
            new_arr.append(Fc)
        elif pixel < 0.2:
            new_arr.append(0.944)
        else:
            new_arr.append(pixel)

    return [new_arr]

terrain['arr'] = terrain['arr'].str.decode('utf-8')
terrain['new_ary'] = terrain['arr'].apply(lambda x: arr_logic(x))

print(terrain.dtypes)
print(terrain)
```

Comment: This is very good, but it generates a problem that I have commented `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'` @KJDII This is due to the NaN values. Is that treating the NaN values as str

Comment: Do you have a sample of terrain['ndvi_matrix'] before you create the array? Sounds like you may need to preprocess that information to get `np.nan` and `floats`

Comment: I can only get this, I can't get it whole   `b'[[NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.36016..`

Comment: Updated handle the `b'[[NaN, ...` example.

Comment: Thanks, this code helped me. I did not know that a lambda function could be used in ndarrays

Answer (score 1):

Input data:

```
>>> terrain
   terrain_id  ndvi_matrix
0           5  [[0.8217155552979787, 0.3099672115904418, 0.6266277523163207], [0.11725795982601384, 0.7234050380206947, 0.23432585428525776], [0.14658855068952603, 0.9934660058726204, 0.5843251036416421]]
1           9  [[0.20367346628943583, NaN, 0.8183039429570168], [NaN, NaN, NaN], [0.3480401851147674, NaN, NaN], [0.3897797899361942, 0.9695928756461897, 0.006497296226907423], [0.7678232526089657, 0.017039908371399903, 0.07803224625341965]]
2          10  [[0.8110310466645949, 0.5694625468868105], [0.330177274386086, 0.8385546531259933], [0.8823223193531003, 0.6800801476410133], [NaN, NaN]]
3          18  [[0.5399031981387157, NaN, 0.9930978186475411, 0.3830175767189744, 0.7685109432532721], [0.022656103788886273, 0.3860560747385754, 0.9699605735947163, 0.036483440273193946, 0.13789939109679117]]
4          19  [[NaN, 0.5062668350287397, 0.05922667405589466, NaN], [0.706118039096498, 0.13114569212422644, 0.9806901059099363, NaN], [0.9248269745262615, 0.6596793327690313, 0.43770577542377953, 0.11179684532285561]]
5          23  [[NaN, 0.6472524121862453, 0.29064151921529846, 0.49507164285810745], [0.6584281587251608, 0.8381562631806461, NaN, 0.4492074246342629]]
6          24  [[0.3711511153060173, NaN, 0.19832511498034666, 0.8604071320413275, 0.45380975705391313], [0.709501182520755, 0.590680803287601, 0.7832281301037608, 0.1150537088106176, 0.48021625141228275], [0.45883798079380966, NaN, 0.35899605566841897, NaN, 0.05813644920490424], [0.22258381790125448, NaN, 0.48509936372932805, 0.48675292417904825, 0.3110740604822009]]
7          26  [[NaN, 0.885255163613397], [0.6864001511014625, NaN], [0.5793096811692588, NaN], [NaN, 0.8727310784076551], [0.650092442108687, NaN]]
8          29  [[NaN, 0.8262184756213229, NaN, 0.3138323965010388, NaN], [0.644053291959643, 0.5339976526420492, NaN, 0.7486133307776289, NaN], [0.2573179543021944, NaN, 0.36980289291571045, NaN, NaN], [0.9866585953070125, NaN, 0.18845706290927178, 0.986040466809015, NaN]]
9          36  [[NaN, 0.3351322849176379, NaN, 0.6663735283696609, NaN], [0.6755852782079985, NaN, NaN, 0.8554058123116294, 0.9132271353603988], [0.7249084160159946, 0.691724896507485, NaN, 0.5223203096525957, NaN]]
```

I assume `ndvi_matrix` type of each row is `str` because you use `json.loads()`.
I guess you convert your list representation to `np.array`.

```
>>> terrain.loc[9, "ndvi_matrix"]
'[[NaN, 0.3351322849176379, NaN, 0.6663735283696609, NaN], [0.6755852782079985, NaN, NaN, 0.8554058123116294, 0.9132271353603988], [0.7249084160159946, 0.691724896507485, NaN, 0.5223203096525957, NaN]]'

>>> type(terrain.loc[9, "ndvi_matrix"])
str
```

You just need another step of conversion:

```
terrain["ndvi_matrix"] = terrain["ndvi_matrix"].map(lambda a: np.array(eval(a.replace("NaN", "'nan'")), dtype=float))
```

```
>>> terrain.loc[9, "ndvi_matrix"]
array([[       nan, 0.33513228,        nan, 0.66637353,        nan],
       [0.67558528,        nan,        nan, 0.85540581, 0.91322714],
       [0.72490842, 0.6917249 ,        nan, 0.52232031,        nan]])

>>> type(terrain.loc[9, "ndvi_matrix"])
numpy.ndarray
```

Now you can process your data:

```
def arr_logic(arr):
    new_arr = np.empty(arr.shape)
    new_arr[:] = np.nan

    # boolean indexing
    m1 = arr > 0.5
    m2 = (0.2 < arr) & (arr < 0.5)
    m3 = arr < 0.2

    # !!! When arr==0.2 or arr==0.5 then new_arr=nan !!!

    # apply your rules
    new_arr[m1] = 0.99
    new_arr[m2] = (arr[m2] - 0.2)**2 / 0.09
    new_arr[m3] = 0.944

    # all other values are already nan
    return new_arr

terrain["ndvi_matrix"] = terrain["ndvi_matrix"].apply(arr_logic)
```

Output data:

```
>>> terrain
terrain_id     ndvi_matrix
0           5  [[0.99, 0.1343643069441889, 0.99], [0.944, 0.99, 0.013091825249030532], [0.944, 0.99, 0.99]]
1           9  [[0.00014993727310690436, nan, 0.99], [nan, nan, nan], [0.24350996009794001, nan, nan], [0.40018187409140005, 0.99, 0.944], [0.99, 0.944, 0.944]]
2          10  [[0.99, 0.99], [0.1882902529621147, 0.99], [0.99, 0.99], [nan, nan]]
3          18  [[0.99, nan, 0.99, 0.3721714820898409, 0.99], [0.944, 0.3846318105236261, 0.99, 0.944, 0.944]]
4          19  [[nan, 0.99, 0.944, nan], [0.99, 0.944, 0.99, nan], [0.99, 0.99, 0.6278226185535589, 0.944]]
5          23  [[nan, 0.99, 0.0912876111739702, 0.9674141602109168], [0.99, 0.99, nan, 0.6900482276982424]]
6          24  [[0.3254744918943736, nan, 0.944, 0.99, 0.7157710308418489], [0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 0.944, 0.872457195061685], [0.7444122255712953, nan, 0.2808860635346109, nan, 0.944], [0.005666987011078019, nan, 0.9031294133207521, 0.9136359947248333, 0.13708274346670685]]
7          26  [[nan, 0.99], [0.99, nan], [0.99, nan], [nan, 0.99], [0.99, nan]]
8          29  [[nan, 0.99, nan, 0.1439757165907745, nan], [0.99, 0.99, nan, 0.99, nan], [0.03650386539320493, nan, 0.32036691602826917, nan, nan], [0.99, nan, 0.944, 0.99, nan]]
9          36  [[nan, 0.2028970491895741, nan, 0.99, nan], [0.99, nan, nan, 0.99, 0.99], [0.99, 0.99, nan, 0.99, nan]]
```

Comment: Thank you. But I used the code from @KJDII, because the conversion worked for me, however the map function would not let me use it in my code. I am sorry I did not fully explain myself about my data. Anyway, the arr_logic function worked for me. Thanks